# HTML background color not changing using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a simple code that has a div with a background color of blue and a submit button. Now, If I click the submit button, the background color of the div should change to red. But the code is not working according to the desired output.

```js
function click(){
 document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor="red";
}
```

```css
#box{
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
 <html>
 <title>PRACTICE</title>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="practicestyle.css"/>
  <script src="practicescript.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 
 <div id="box"></div>
 <form>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="click()">
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Clicking the submit button will submit your form, that will load the page again, that means everything you changed via JS on the “previous” page is gone.

Comment: There are two problems here. Looking for a duplicate for the second one.

Comment: you have to prevent the submit action & use ajax to submit the data ow use type="button" instead of submit

Comment: @amyloula The propagation is not relevant here. They need to call `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

you have used submit instead of button please  go through this

> Button Types There are three types of buttons:
>
> submit — Submits the current form data. (This is default.)                           reset —
>   Resets data in the current form. button — Just a button. Its effects
>   must be controlled by something else (that is, with JavaScript).